# Am I running NIS?

Tags: dns

I am pretty new to ubuntu 16, but I was reading this

[Securing and optimizing Linux RH Edition](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec71.html)

and my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` had this in it

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        compat



hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

so I replaced it with this

```
        hosts:  dns files
        passwd:files
        shadow:files
        group:files
        hosts:dns files
        bootparams:files
        ethers:files
        netmasks:files
        networks:files
        protocols:files
        rpc:files
        services:files
        automount:files
        aliases:files
```

so my question is before i make everything permanent 
how do I know whether I'm running NIS?

`/etc/rc.conf` was empty

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not running `NIS`, but see `nisdomainname` for confirmation:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ nisdomainname 
nisdomainname: Local domain name not set
w3@aardvark:~(1)$
```

`NIS` (Network Information System, formerly Yellow Pages) was used in corporate network support, and is not normally used anymore.

I question your changes on the other lines, as well. How well do you understand the consequences of enduring DNS timeouts before you can lookup locally stored hostnames (a consequence of `hosts:  dns files`)?

In general, blindly applying recipes from "**Securing and Optimizing Linux: RedHat Edition -A Hands on Guide**" to Ubuntu 16.04.1 cannot be expected to just "work". Ubuntu is manufactured by Canonical, Red Hat Linux is manufactured by Red Hat. Each company configures its Linux-based product differently.

More generally, blindly applying recipes from anywhere is not a Good Idea. It's worth the effort to understand what you're doing, and that you're not about to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: thank you so much, i researched more on the ubuntu manual @ manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html